# Angular - Active route still appears when I am not on the route

Tags: angular, angular-routing

Here is an example of what I have: [my code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example-drt2mc?file=app%2Fapp.routing.module.ts,app%2Fapp.component.ts).

I tried to make my `LoginComponent` to be my "empty" path, and to appear without a specific router name in my URL, and it is working. Although, he still appears as the `active`route, I even putted `pathMatch: 'full'`, but didn't work...

[image] [image]

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running in to the problem that angular router resolves `/` as an path, and that exists in `/Catalog`.

You can use `[routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}"` on your login a tag, making it.

```
<a routerLinkActive="active" 
   [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}"
   routerLink="">Login</a>
```

[Forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example-tb9csc?file=app/app.component.ts)